# In "Me l'ha data", why "me" instead of "mi"

Tags: grammar, pronouns

From my understanding, *me* as a clitic is reserved for tonic clitics (stressed). And as indirect pronoun, in this instance shouldn't we use *mi* instead?

PS: this is one of the translation question from Duolingo.

Comment: Languages are funny! I'm pretty sure you can find *Lo mi disse* in some (very) old Italian text, when the inversion of the pronouns was pretty common, but not “mi lo disse”. In the sentence you're asking about, *me* is unstressed clitic as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mi*, *ti*, *si*, *ci* and *vi*, if followed by the pronoun *ne*, become *me*, *te*, *se*, *ce*, *ve*. The same happens if they are followed by *lo*, *la*, *li*, *le*.

Examples:
*Me lo ha detto lui* (*Lui mi ha detto una cosa*)
*Te la ha data lei, questa notizia* (*Ti ha dato lei questa notizia*); “*Te l'ha data*” is the same as “*te la ha data*”.

Answer (score 0):

When followed by a **direct object pronoun**, the pronouns *mi*, *ti*, *ci*, *vi* and *si* are replaced with *me*, *te*, *ce*, *ve* and *se*, respectively.

The same rule applies to *gli*, but together with the direct pronoun it must be replaced with a contracted form:

gli + lo => glielo, gli + la => gliela, etc...

You can find a better and more thorough explanation [here](http://www.zanichellibenvenuti.it/wordpress/?p=2144)